# Interactively ask user for filename before saving file

Tags: r

I want to save the my  tab delim files manually. I mean that I want user to choose the directory and file name when he wants to save the data.  (For an example I have merged individual files into single file and want to save it.)

Usually I use `write.table` but in `write.table` we define the directory path and file name within that function but I want a function in which user can save file with any name in his desired directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Annoyingly the tcltk package doesn't have a function for 'Save As', it only has a file selector for choosing an existing file.

Luckily you can take the DIY approach via some tcl calls:

```
require(tcltk)
write.table(yerdata,file = tclvalue(tcl("tk_getSaveFile")))
```

The `tk_choose.files` function source could be used as a template to write a nicer interface to tcl("tk_getSaveFile") if needed. Does seem to be a glaring omission in package:tcltk though...

Answer (score 12):

Just use the `file.choose()` function,like this:

```
write.table(yerdata, file = file.choose(new = TRUE))
```

On Windows, at least, that will bring up a dialog for save-as commands.

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion but it opens OS-standard dialog for save-as commands and there is no option for save.there is only open.

Comment: Doesn't matter - just type in the file name you want and hit open.  If the file doesn't exist, R will ask if you want to create it.

Comment: That advice needs to be considered OS-specific (does not succeed on a Mac.)

Comment: @DWin - thanks!  I had no idea.  The help file mentions nothing about platform specificity, so I just assumed it would work everywhere else.

Comment: @DWin Is it specifically the creation of new files that doesn't work on Macs?

Comment: Right. Works fine for selecting existing files. Graphics, encodings, date-times, and system calls are more likely to be OS specific.

Comment: @MattParker Welcome. I'm so new at R, but glad I could lend a hand.

Answer (score 1):

Using `gWidgets`:

```
gfile("Save yerdata", type = "save", handler = function(h, ...)
{
  write.table(yerdata, file = h$file)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

One (perhaps less than ideal) option would be to use `readline` to prompt the user for the full path and file name (or just the file name if you want to programmatically choose the directory) and then simply pass that value on the `write.table`. Here's a sketch:

```
FILE_PATH <- readline(prompt = "Enter a full path and file name: ")
#Some checking to make sure you got a valid file path...
write.table(yerdata, file = FILE_PATH)
```

Note that as per `?readline` this will really only work when running R interactively.

Answer (score 0):

As it is 2017 now, the `tcltk2` package is an improvement of `tcltk`:

```
library(tcltk2)
filename <- tclvalue(tkgetSaveFile())
if (!nchar(filename)) {
  tkmessageBox(message = "No file was selected!")
} else {
  tkmessageBox(message = paste("The file selected was", filename))
}
```

And the use of filters, let's say one should only save as JPG/JPEG:

```
jpeg_filename <- tclvalue(
  tkgetSaveFile(initialfile = "foo.jpg",
                filetypes = "{ {JPEG Files} {.jpg .jpeg} } { {All Files} * }")
)
```